# Need to add a space to a zip code field with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need in a form to add a space in the zip code field, at the third from the last character. It's international zip codes, hence this is why I need this.

So for example, someone enters:

xxxxxx123

as their zip code, I need it to be reformatted as:

xxxxxx 123

at least upon submit.

Here is what I have started with, but I don't know where to go from here...

```
function addSpaceToZip()
{
    zip = $U.getObj('zip').value;
    zipLength = zip.length; 
    zipNewLength =  
}
```

Comment: *"I have been unsuccessful at this so far."* What have you tried? If you show us what you've done, we can help you understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be to just use the baked in substring function.

```
function addSpaceToZip()
{
   var zip = $U.getObj('zip').value;
   return zip.substring(0, zip.length - 3) + ' ' + zip.substring(zip.length - 3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you gstephas. Although my question wasn't super clear, that helped.